# retrieve stored image in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have images stored in my database i want to load them in the browser i have two pages one of them is

`show_picture.php` and the other one is `get_image.php` my image `contents` does not load in the browser and it is like that the image has been moved or something but the images are stored in database so here is my code

```
 <?php include("includes/student_session.php");?>
<?php confirm_logged_in();?>
<html>
<body>
<?php include("includes/connection.php");?>
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['exam_id']) and isset($_SESSION['register_id'])){

$exam_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_SESSION['exam_id']);

$query="select question_id from questions where exam_id={$exam_id} order by page_number asc";
$result=mysqli_query($cnn,$query);
if($result){

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<img src=\"get_image.php?id={$row['question_id']}\"/>";   
    }
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my get_image.php

```
    <?php include("includes/connection.php");?>
<?php 
$question_id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query="select question from questions where question_id={$question_id} limit 1";
$result=mysqli_query($cnn,$query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  //mysql_close($cnn);

  header("Content-type: image/jpg");
  echo $row['question'];
?>
```

I am wondering what i am missing

Comment: my problem is that the images does not load completely 20% of them loads for example

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($cnn))` to `mysqli_query()` - `session_start();` is loaded, correct?

Comment: the problem was my last login session, solved thanks